# Lean predicate logic problem. existentially quantified proposition

Tags: lean

I am trying to prove a theorem using lean and I am unsure on how to fix the rest of my code. I am trying to prove with these 2 premises h₁ : ∀ x, P(x) → Q(x), h₂ : ∃ y, P(y) ∨ Q(y) that ∃ z, Q(z). The code I have so far has reached this point however I am still facing errors. Could anyone advise me on what to do? Thank you.

```
namespace exlean  
variables (X : Type*) (P Q : X → Prop) 
theorem ass4  (h₁ : ∀ x, P(x) → Q(x))
              (h₂ : ∃ y, P(y) ∨ Q(y))  :
  ∃ z, Q(z)  :=
begin
cases h₂ with z h₃, 
{given h₃ : P z ∨ Q z,
cases h₃ with h₄ h₅, 
{given h₄ : P z, 
show ∃ z, Q z, from h₄ h₁, 
},

{given h₅ : Q z,
show ∃ z, Q z, exact h₅,
},
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof written in Lean 4:

```
example {α : Sort u} {p q : α → Prop} (h₁ : ∀ x, p x → q x)
    (h₂ : ∃ x, p x ∨ q x) : ∃ x, q x :=
  let ⟨w, hpqw⟩ := h₂
  match hpqw with
  | Or.inl hpw => ⟨w, h₁ w hpw⟩
  | Or.inr hqw => ⟨w, hqw⟩
```